# Fatal error: value failed to bridge from Swift type to an Objective-C type - When using Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using the following project https://github.com/indragiek/MarkdownTextView and have enable Core Data to save the text from the `UITextView`.

Everything works fine regarding saving the text and using the markdown, that is until I start change some of the text attributes in the `viewDidLoad`. I have followed the example on the GitHub page on how to change the attributes, but still have the error.

Here's an example of what I am doing,

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import MarkdownKit

var textStorage: MarkdownTextStorage?
var textView: MarkdownTextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    var attributes = MarkdownAttributes()

    let fontFloat = CGFloat(28)


    attributes.headerAttributes?.h6Attributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 20)!
    ]

    attributes.defaultAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: fontFloat)!
    ]

    attributes.strongAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()
    ]

    let textStorage = MarkdownTextStorage(attributes: attributes)


    do {
        textStorage.addHighlighter(try LinkHighlighter())
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("Error initializing LinkHighlighter: \(error)")
    }
    textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownStrikethroughHighlighter())
    textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownSuperscriptHighlighter())

    if let codeBlockAttributes = attributes.codeBlockAttributes {
        textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownFencedCodeHighlighter(attributes: codeBlockAttributes))
    }

    textView = MarkdownTextView(frame: CGRectZero, textStorage: textStorage)
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(textView)

    let views = ["textView": textView]
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-60-[textView]-8-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-8-[textView]-8-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)


    textView.delegate = self

    userSettings()

}
```

Sometimes it's fine and the `ViewController` loads with all the custom attributes but other times I get the following error,

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here's how the MarkdownAttributes struct sets the attributes from within the framework,

```
public var defaultAttributes: TextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
]

public var h1Attributes: TextAttributes? = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
]
```

Does anybody know what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 20)!
```

Here's you're force-unwrapping your `UIFont` initializer, even though it is defined as a failable initializer (`init?`).  You probably don't have that font installed correctly, and this call is returning `nil` instead of a `UIFont` instance.

Here's an example of how you would guard against a `nil` font:

```
attributes.headerAttributes?.h6Attributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()
]

if let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 20) {
    attributes.headerAttributes?.h6Attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font
} else {
    attributes.headerAttributes?.h6Attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)
}
```

Comment: I actually have the fonts correctly installed I have checked and changed other labels to the text. I did delete the `!` so I do not force unwrap however then I get the inline error `Value of optional type 'UIFont?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: @JKSDEV updated my answer with a potential solution to unwrap the font.  If OpenSans can't be found, I fall back on the system font.